# How to use translateX and translateY in D3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I built a dragging event and I want the element to be dragged only when the coordinates are multiples of 10:

```
    const x = d3.event.x
    const y = d3.event.y

    if (x % 10 === 0) {
      d3.select(this)
        .attr('transform', 'translateX(' + x + ')')
    }

    if (y % 10 === 0) {
      d3.select(this)
        .attr('transform', 'translateY(' + y + ')')
    }
```

However, I get errors like this when I drag:

```
Error: Invalid value for <rect> attribute transform="translateX(180)"
```

Maybe I'm using the translate property in the wrong way? What's the correct way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no attribute as translateX/translateY

You can do the above like this.

```
    const x = d3.event.x
        const y = d3.event.y
   //old translate
    var translate = d3.transform(d3.select(this).attr("transform")).translate;
        if (x % 10 === 0) {
          //maintain the y translate to old
          d3.select(this)
            .attr('transform', 'translate(' + x +','+ translate[1]+')')
        }

        if (y % 10 === 0) {
          d3.select(this)
          //maintain the x translate to old
            .attr('transform', 'translate(' + translate[0] +','+ y+')')
        }
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

The error you're getting is because "translateX" is not a valid transform for an SVG element (looks like you're using d3.js to generate SVG elements in the DOM).

Valid transform values can be found on MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform).

I'm not certain that `transform` is really what you want based on your description of the problem, but at any rate simply removing the "X" should do it. For example:

```
if (x % 10 === 0) {
    d3.select(this)
        .attr('transform', 'translate('+x+')');
}
```

Be aware that `translate()` takes arguments x and y. If you only provide one argument, it is assumed to be x, and y will be set to 0.

Again, note that while d3 is helping you select the element, all that's really happening here is you're setting the `transform` property on an svg `rect` element.